# Could not find the selected project in the reactor Maven : Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, artifacts

I’m using Jenkins to build a multi-module Maven project. Recently, I removed a module from our parent pom

when we run the build in Jenkins with the following options …

```
mvn -T 8C clean install -PTata
```

However, the build ultimately fails with the below  error.

`“Could not find the selected project in the reactor: com.customization:Avg”`

**Project Structure**

```
- src
    Customization
          Tata
          Avg
          Qlip
```

Suggest to solve this issue...

Comment: And does the project exist? Can you post the structure of your multi-module project?